# Transparent JTextField and JLabel to show background image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, jtextfield

I'm having difficulty with the JTextField and JLabel not appearing with an image in the background of my JFrame. I've set the opacities to false using .setOpaque(false); but it is not working. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
package Game;

import javax.swing.*;

//window

public class Frame {

    public void window(){//window method

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter a Letter");
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
        jl.setOpaque(false);  
        jl.setBorder(null);
        jp.add(jl);
        jp.add(tf);


    LoadImageApp i = new LoadImageApp();
    i.setOpaque(false);

    JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();//declaration
    gameFrame.getContentPane().add(jp);
    gameFrame.add(i);//adds image to window
    gameFrame.setTitle("Hangman");//title of frame window
    gameFrame.setSize(850, 600);//set size of frame
    gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//exit when 'x' button pressed
    gameFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("Hangman-Game-grey.png").getImage());//set the frame icon to an image loaded from a file
    gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//window centered over null(center)
    gameFrame.setResizable(false);
    //gameFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    gameFrame.setVisible(true);//display frame


}   
}





package Game;

//import statements

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LoadImageApp extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private ImageIcon image;

        public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            image = new ImageIcon("hangman.png");
            image.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 9);
        }
}





package Game;

//main class

public class GameMain {
    public static void main (String []args){
        Frame frame = new Frame();//declaration
        frame.window();//window call
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gameFrame.getContentPane().add(jp);
gameFrame.add(i);//adds image to window
```

The above code should be something like:

```
gameFrame.add(i); //adds background image to window
i.add( jp ); // add panel containing label to background image panel
```

Also, you should NOT be doing I/O in any painting method. Painting methods can be called whenever Swing determines a component needs to be repainted. The image should be read when the class is created.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the painting method and possibly give me an example?Can you show me the most efficient way of coding the painting method. Can you also show me how to change the position of my JTextField and JLabel.

Comment: Swing was designed to be used with [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Use an appropriate layout manager or panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired result.